# Data step - unexpected performance behaviour in where-clause

Tags: sas

As the title suggests, I experience some unexpected performance behaviour while working with a datastep.

**A.**  The following code executes in 0.01 sec. So far so good.

```
data policen_roh;
    set dwhprod.tbwh_kdu_detail_hi(
        keep=
        kdu_dt_id police_nr record_typ kdnr bag betrag_akt ursp_beginn_dt beginn_dt ablauf_dt storno_dt
        where=(
        police_nr=406045267 
        and record_typ='P' 
        )
        )
    ;
run;
```

**B.** Additionally I have to filter a date, which is stored in a date-id, starting at `1` for `01/01/1850`. Since I created formats to convert the date-id to a year (integer), I added the line `input(put(kdu_dt_id, tag_id2jahr.),best.) ge 2017`.

Works as expected. No problem here. I get my 15 expected records, and execution time increases marginally to 0.02 sec:

```
data policen_roh;
    set dwhprod.tbwh_kdu_detail_hi(
        keep=
        kdu_dt_id police_nr record_typ kdnr bag betrag_akt ursp_beginn_dt beginn_dt ablauf_dt storno_dt
        where=(
        police_nr=406045267 
        and input(put(kdu_dt_id, tag_id2jahr.),best.) ge 2017
        and record_typ='P' 
        )
        )
    ;
run;
```

**C.** **Now here is the problem:** In an effort to speed up my code for larger datasets, I replaced

`input(put(kdu_dt_id, tag_id2jahr.),best.) ge 2017`

with

`kdu_dt_id gt 60997` - the equivalent of `01/01/2017`.

To my understanding, this should be way faster, since there is no put/input calculation required. However, while this returns the same result as B., execution time increases to roughly 30.00 seconds.

**What is did I miss?**

---

**Appendix:** Log for further reference

```
1                                                          The SAS System                          13:56 Wednesday, February 7, 2018

1          ;*';*";*/;quit;run;
2          OPTIONS PAGENO=MIN;
3          %LET _CLIENTTASKLABEL='Programm';
4          %LET _CLIENTPROJECTPATH='R:\Projekte\20180125 Erneuerungsprovisionen\Erneuerungsprovisionen.egp';
5          %LET _CLIENTPROJECTNAME='Erneuerungsprovisionen.egp';
6          %LET _SASPROGRAMFILE=;
7          
8          ODS _ALL_ CLOSE;
9          OPTIONS DEV=ACTIVEX;
10         GOPTIONS XPIXELS=0 YPIXELS=0;
11         FILENAME EGHTML TEMP;
12         ODS HTML(ID=EGHTML) FILE=EGHTML
13             ENCODING='utf-8'
14             STYLE=HtmlBlue
15             STYLESHEET=(URL="file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/SASHOME/x86/SASEnterpriseGuide/7.1/Styles/HtmlBlue.css")
16             ATTRIBUTES=("CODEBASE"="http://www2.sas.com/codebase/graph/v94/sasgraph.exe#version=9,4")
17             NOGTITLE
18             NOGFOOTNOTE
19             GPATH=&sasworklocation
20         ;
NOTE: Writing HTML(EGHTML) Body file: EGHTML
21         
22         GOPTIONS ACCESSIBLE;
23         data policen_roh;
24             set dwhprod.tbwh_kdu_detail_hi(
25                 keep=
26                 kdu_dt_id police_nr record_typ kdnr bag betrag_akt ursp_beginn_dt beginn_dt ablauf_dt storno_dt
27                 where=(
28                 police_nr=406045267
29                 and kdu_dt_id gt 60997
30                 and record_typ='P'
31                 )
32                 )
33             ;
34         run;

NOTE: There were 14 observations read from the data set DWHPROD.TBWH_KDU_DETAIL_HI.
      WHERE (police_nr=406045267) and (kdu_dt_id>60997) and (record_typ='P');
NOTE: The data set WORK.POLICEN_ROH has 14 observations and 10 variables.
NOTE: Compressing data set WORK.POLICEN_ROH increased size by 100.00 percent. 
      Compressed is 2 pages; un-compressed would require 1 pages.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           1:10.44
      cpu time            0.03 seconds


35         
36         GOPTIONS NOACCESSIBLE;
37         %LET _CLIENTTASKLABEL=;
38         %LET _CLIENTPROJECTPATH=;
39         %LET _CLIENTPROJECTNAME=;
40         %LET _SASPROGRAMFILE=;
41         
42         ;*';*";*/;quit;run;
43         ODS _ALL_ CLOSE;
44         
45         
46         QUIT; RUN;
2                                                          The SAS System                          13:56 Wednesday, February 7, 2018

47
```

Comment: did you run this multiple times with the same result?  Can you post the log so we can see exactly what was submitted?  You can also try `options sastrace=',,,d' sastraceloc=saslog;` for more information on the query sent to `dwhprod`..

Comment: Yes, ran it several times with comparable long execution times. I just re-ran it and posted the Log. Looks like only the "real time" is that long, while the cpu time is comparably short to the other methods.

Comment: Please show the libname statement that defines `dwhprod`.  If it connects to a remote data base, that system may be caching results.  Also,  `OPTIONS MSGLEVEL=I;` will log the use of any indices if the library engine is native SAS.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your underlying table is on a database, and the removal of the input / put functions changed the query execution such that it is no longer making use of available indexes.

A bit counterintuitive, but try removing `kdu_dt_id gt 60997` from your where clause and put it in a gating `if` statement instead.

```
data policen_roh;
    set dwhprod.tbwh_kdu_detail_hi(
        keep=
        kdu_dt_id police_nr record_typ kdnr bag betrag_akt ursp_beginn_dt beginn_dt ablauf_dt storno_dt
        where=(
        police_nr=406045267 
        and record_typ='P' 
        )
        )
    ;
  if kdu_dt_id gt 60997;
run;
```

Alternatively speak to your dba about tuning your database if this is a query you will run often.

For more information, you could re-write your query using proc sql, with the `_tree` option (to view the execution plan).  You could then use the `_method` option to play around / tune that plan.

Also, check out `options sastrace=',,,d' sastraceloc=saslog;` to show your dba more info on what is being sent to the database in terms of the underlying SQL query.

Comment: While there is no different result, I will look into the logs some more with the options you mentioned... quite a lot to digest, but i will look into it tonight and report my findings